# Ranking Placing Query in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `player` and `player_friend`. The table `player` has three fields: 'id', 'level' and 'username'. The table `player_friend` has two fields: 'player_id' and 'friend_id'. I can get all places in the ranking by querying `player`, sorting by 'level' and the index of the row in the result is the placing in the ranking:

```
SELECT (username, level) FROM player SORT BY level;
```

How do I query the placing in the ranking, username and level of entries in the `player_friend` 'friend_id' where 'player_id' = x?

For example:

#### player

```
id | username | level
 1 |        a |     1
 2 |        b |     3
 3 |        c |     2
 4 |        d |     5
```

#### player_friend

```
player_id | friend_id
        4 |         1
        4 |         2
```

expected results:

```
placing | username | level
      2 |        b |     3
      4 |        a |     1
```

Explanation: friend with username "b" is the second in the global ranking and friend with username "a" is the global ranking (sorting by level), in the example it is not visible but it is only showing where `player_friend` 'player_id' is 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from player_friend pf join
     (select p.*, row_number() over (order by level) as placing
      from player p
     ) p
    on pf.friend_id = p.id;
```